# DNS not working in firejail

Tags: ubuntu, security, dns, firejail

I try to make a test ssh firejail user for testing downloaded files.
But the name lookup for my setup is not working.
/etc/passwd:

```
UserName:x:9999:9999:,,,:/home/UserName:/usr/bin/firejail
```

/etc/firejail/login.users:

```
UserName:--private --net=wlp3s0 --dns=8.8.8.8 --dns=8.8.4.4 --netfilter=/etc/firejail/nolocal.net
```

I can't do a wget from google or any other site.
Can you please help me to find the error?

Comment: Can you ping from jail by IP, such as `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: No but from outside the jail