# No internet: firejail ubuntu 20.04 --net=eno1 --dns=QQQ.RRR.SSS.TTT

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, sandbox, firejail

This is the same case of unanswered question [DNS not working in firejail](https://superuser.com/questions/1177398/dns-not-working-in-firejail)

ALL SENSITIVE INFORMATION WAS MODIFIED TO A SET OF THREE OR TWO LETTERS (AAA, etc. or XX)

The case is:
I have an ethernet connection on device eno1 I'll use to access company's intranet, and a Wi-fi connection on device wlp0s20f3 I'll access internet.

If I run `firejail --noprofile --nonewprivs --noroot --net=eno1  --hostname=intranet --name=intranet --debug --dns=AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD`, where AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD is my company's DNS server, I get no internet, no intranet although `ip a` shows:

> 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
> (...)

> 2: eth0-10765@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
> (...)

This "eth0-10765@if2" is not one of Ubuntu bare metal NICs.

`ip route show` outputs:

> default via AAA.BBB.CCC.XXX dev eth0-10765
> AAA.BBB.CCC.0/24 dev eth0-10765 proto kernel scope link src AAA.BBB.CCC.ZZZ

ZZZ is to display it's not the same number as 'default via' (XXX).

This is a piece of the sandbox "boot" output:

> sbox run: /run/firejail/lib/fnet ifup eth0-10765
> Set caps filter 3000
> ARP-scan eth0-10765, AAA.BBB.CCC.39/24
> IP address range from AAA.BBB.CCC.1 to AAA.BBB.CCC.255
> Trying AAA.BBB.CCC.ZZZ ...
> Configuring AAA.BBB.CCC.ZZZ address on interface eth0-10765
> sbox run: /run/firejail/lib/fnet config interface eth0-10765 2886891220 4294967040 1500
> Set caps filter 3000
> Announce AAA.BBB.CCC.ZZZ ...
> Network namespace enabled

> sbox run: /run/firejail/lib/fnet printif
> Set caps filter 3000
> Interface        MAC                IP               Mask             Status
> lo                                  127.0.0.1        255.0.0.0        UP
> ::1
> eth0-10765       XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  AAA.BBB.CCC.ZZZ  255.255.255.0    UP
> XX::XX:XX:XX:XX
> Default gateway AAA.BBB.CCC.XXX
> DNS server QQQ.RRR.SSS.TTT

> Drop privileges: pid 6, uid 1000, gid 1000, force_nogroups 0
> Supplementary groups: 24
> Mounting /proc filesystem representing the PID namespace
> Basic read-only filesystem:
> Mounting read-only /etc
> 1096 1048 259:6 /etc /etc ro,relatime master:1 - ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p6 rw,errors=remount-ro

ping command is not available, but I can run any browser and no internet/intranet/proxy authentication message, whatsoever.

On the other hand, if I set up a sandbox to work with wi-fi only, thus expecting an internet connection, using the command `$ firejail --noprofile --nonewprivs --noroot --net=wlp0s20f3  --hostname=internet --name=internet --debug --dns=8.8.8.8 --caps.drop=all --dbus-system=none` I still have no internet whatsoever on browsers!

I even tried to move the interface to the sandbox using the command
`firejail --noprofile --interface=eno1  --hostname=intranet --ipc-namespace --name=intranet --debug`
It really removes the interface from bare metal system and makes it available to the sandbox, but no internet nor default gateway!
This is the excerpt from the sandbox "boot":

> sbox run: /run/firejail/lib/fnet ifup lo
> Set caps filter 3000
> Configuring AAA.BBB.CCC.39 address on interface eno1
> sbox run: /run/firejail/lib/fnet config interface eno1 2886891047 4294967040 1500
> Set caps filter 3000
> Network namespace enabled

> sbox run: /run/firejail/lib/fnet printif
> Set caps filter 3000
> Interface        MAC                IP               Mask             Status
> lo                                  127.0.0.1        255.0.0.0        UP
> ::1
> eno1             XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  AAA.BBB.CCC.39   255.255.255.0    DOWN

> Drop privileges: pid 5, uid 1000, gid 1000, force_nogroups 0
> Mounting /proc filesystem representing the PID namespace
> Basic read-only filesystem:
> Mounting read-only /etc
> 1097 1048 259:6 /etc /etc ro,relatime master:1 - ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p6 rw,errors=remount-ro

Another weird thing is that inside the sandbox systemd-resolve appears to be unable to read information for eno1:

`$ sudo systemd-resolve --status --no-pager`

> Global
> LLMNR setting: no                   MulticastDNS setting: no                     DNSOverTLS setting: no
> DNSSEC setting: no
> DNSSEC supported: no
> DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
> 16.172.in-addr.arpa
> 168.192.in-addr.arpa
> 17.172.in-addr.arpa
> 18.172.in-addr.arpa
> 19.172.in-addr.arpa
> 20.172.in-addr.arpa
> 21.172.in-addr.arpa
> 22.172.in-addr.arpa
> 23.172.in-addr.arpa
> 24.172.in-addr.arpa
> 25.172.in-addr.arpa
> 26.172.in-addr.arpa
> 27.172.in-addr.arpa
> 28.172.in-addr.arpa
> 29.172.in-addr.arpa
> 30.172.in-addr.arpa
> 31.172.in-addr.arpa
> corp
> d.f.ip6.arpa
> home
> internal
> intranet
> lan
> local
> private
> test                 Failed to get link data for 2: Unknown object '/org/freedesktop/resolve1/link/_32'.

All this situation makes me think something's wrong with how Ubuntu deals with namespaces, networks and interfaces and how firejail deals with the same.
I have the possibility to use another distro if I can be sure this kind of operation will work.
On the other hand I'm a complete newbie to namespaces but very curious and interested, it would be great if you could tip me about how to run what I'm willing using my set-up, with or without firejail.

A few more info:

`$ uname -a`

> Linux Ubuntu 5.15.0-69-generic #76~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 20 15:54:19 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`$ firejail --version`

> firejail version 0.9.73
>
> Compile time support:
>
> - always force nonewprivs support is disabled
> - AppArmor support is disabled
> - AppImage support is enabled
> - chroot support is enabled
> - D-BUS proxy support is enabled
> - file transfer support is enabled
> - firetunnel support is disabled
> - IDS support is disabled
> - networking support is enabled
> - output logging is enabled
> - overlayfs support is disabled
> - private-home support is enabled
> - private-lib support is disabled
> - private-cache and tmpfs as user enabled
> - SELinux support is enabled
> - user namespace support is enabled
> - X11 sandboxing support is enabled